# Terraform - Use certificate to authenticate azurerm in Remote execution mode

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to authenticate azurerm provider in Terraform IaC using a certificate. I was following below documentation.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret

I am using the agents provided by terraform cloud to run the deployments by setting the execution mode in the workspace as “Remote”. Hence I do not have any access to the machine where the agents are running. Neither I can set the environment variables nor install the certificates on the agents.

I tried using the below code to use certificate.

```
provider “azurerm” {
features {
}
client_id = “xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-123456789”
tenant_id = “xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx”
subscription_id = “xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx”
client_certificate_path = “C:\MyPath\MyFolder\TF\mypfx.pfx”
client_certificate_password = “87654”
}
```

But the terraform plan failed with below error. Can someone please help me in fixing this error? The same code works perfectly fine if I update the code to use client_secret. But I need to make it work with the certificate.

I made sure that the ceritificate is available in the app registraion. And the thumbprint of the certificate in the Azure app registration matches with the one located in “*C:\MyPath\MyFolder\TF\mypfx.pfx*”.

*Error: building account: could not acquire access token to parse claims: clientCredentialsToken: received HTTP status 401 with response: {“error”:“invalid_client”,“error_description”:"AADSTS700027: The certificate with identifier used to sign the client assertion is not registered on application. [Reason - The key was not found., Please visit the Azure Portal, Graph Explorer or directly use MS Graph to see
configured keys for app Id ‘xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-123456789’.*

Comment: Kindly check whether you are using the same application ID where you uploaded the certificate, cross-verify if there are any duplicate names, and also share the screenshot of the certificate uploaded to the Azure AD application by editing the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> The certificate with identifier used to sign the client assertion is not registered on application.

The above error you are encountered is likely due to the **certificate** not being uploaded in the specified application that you are attempting to access using **Terraform code**.

If you have already uploaded the certificate to the application, ensure that you verify the **application ID** being used in the Terraform code.

When attempting to authenticate with a **Service Principal** using a certificate, without uploading the certificate to the application, I encountered the same error.

```html
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  client_id                    = "ac14238dd337d177d8"
  tenant_id                    = "72f988bf-8xxx-2d7cd011db47"
  subscription_id              = "b83c1ed3-xxx-2b83a074c23f"
  client_certificate_path      = "C:\\Venkat\\Azure_AD\\venkatcer.pfx"
  client_certificate_password  = "password"
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "sampledemorg"
  location = "eastus"
}
```

[image]

The issue was resolved after the certificate was uploaded to the correct **Azure AD** application.

[image]

Reference:  [The certificate with identifier used to sign the client assertion is not registered on application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1192414/aadsts700027-the-certificate-with-identifier-used)